# How to spot an empty access field with data reader C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, datareader

I'm trying to create a method that returns a string from my db that fulfills my conditions.

The first condition is working. 
But, the second condition is that part of entry in access is empty, at least one field.

This is my code:

```
OleDbCommand datacommand = new OleDbCommand();
datacommand.Connection = dataConnection;
datacommand.CommandText = "SELECT   numNumber, numLocation " +
                          "FROM     tblNumbers  " +
                          "ORDER BY numID ";
OleDbDataReader dataReader = datacommand.ExecuteReader();
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    if (MatchServiceLetters(dataReader.GetString(0))) // && dataReader.GetInt32(1) == null?/)
}
return dataReader.GetString(0);
```

If the int field is empty, the comparison to null isn't working. so how can I know if it is empty?

Comment: `DBNull` is your friend.

Comment: you can use IsNull: ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )

Comment: t0mm13b You are my hero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN:

> No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must already be a 32-bit signed integer.
>   Call IsDBNull to look for null values before calling this method.

So you would use:

```
if(!dataReader.IsDBNull(1))
{
    return dataReader.GetInt32(1);
}
else
{
    return 0; // or better yet, make your method return Nullable<int>
}
```

Comment: you can replace all that with IsNull(numNumber,0) and it is all handled by SQL

Comment: @Sorceri that is true, but you are starting to mix concerns there.  It isn't uncommon for sprocs to be reused, which can create an issue if NULL is a valid value for that column.  Generally it is not a good idea to use magic values to represent missing data (thus the suggestion to use Nullable types).